# DatePickerand Translation

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a date picker (default one) on which I need to translate the Month column to any other language.

I have not been able to access those fields yet and can't seem to find a proper way of doing so.

Would someone know how I can set that 'picker'choices to the one I want to (ie translated text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    fn: function(element, eOpts) 
    {
        var picker = this.query('pickerslot')[0];
        var store = picker.getStore();

        for (i in LANG.word.months)
        {
            store.getAt(i).data.text=LANG.word.months[i];
        }

        picker.refresh();
    },
    event: 'painted'
}
```

Worked Like a charm, got it was hard to find the proper way